# Adding 'Poop' as a synonym of the 'defecation' tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

This morning I was looking for a duplicate Cat poop question, but we don't have a 'poop' tag, we do have [defecation with 7 questions using it](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/defecation)  so I had to look through 300+ posts with "poop" in them.

I started the process to create tag synonym of [poop for defecation](https://pets.stackexchange.com/tags/defecation/synonyms) which would make it easier to find and use.  But my magic powers are not sufficient to create the synonym.  I am going to be going through and adding 'defecation' questions that should have it.  Hopefully some of you will be able to vote on the synonym as the questions get updated (and you gain rep in the tag).

**EDIT** The synonym suggestion has received enough votes to complete the process.

Comment: update while reviewing, I am seeing a few questions that might be duplicates of the others, I am trying stay on track so am not addressing them.  We could improve our duplicate identification processes.

Comment: poop is a term used by children.  Why not use the correct term "faces" ?

Comment: Actual the term is [feces, and we have that tag](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feces) a word search returns 124 hits while 'poop' returns 321 hits, feces is a noun.  poop is a noun and verb, and used much more by people who post here.  I went through and tagged questions where poop was used as a verb to deification.  I also tagged some as toilet training where that was the more appropriate tag.  The hope of the synonym is that users may try and tag with poop, and put deification on the question.

Comment: Oops, I omitted the "e" in faeces.

Comment: : ) yep, I hate it when I do that.

Comment: [Everything old is new again](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/q/159/31).